# zsh - preview parent directory names when 'cd ../../../'

Tags: zsh

Anyone knows of a way to make zsh show me a preview of the parent directory I would be in if I hit return right now?

For instance, if I'm very deep down a directory tree, and I start typing `....` (which gets expanded into `../../..`), I would like to preview the highest-up folder name that I would end up in with those three jumps up the directory tree.

Comment: It's an awesome question.. I'm looking into how oh-my-zsh does some of its magic to see if that points the direction.

Comment: Thanks @mjb - I haven't found any pointers yet, but I'll update here if I make any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the expansion of `....` to `../../..` happens on-the-fly, so you have a special key binding for `.`. So have I, which was inspired by 
[Jérémie Roquet's post on the zsh users mailing](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2010/msg00770.html) list. I extended this function, called `magic-dot` to display the path, which will be referred to in the *mini buffer*, i.e. below the command line:

```
user@linux:~/foo> ls ../../
[ /home/ ]
```

My code has some disadvantages:

1. it's not optimized and really ugly to read (it even uses `perl` to generate the output)
2. it failes, when symlinks come into play
3. the mini buffer is not cleared, so might be still visible after execution of the command

(Points 1 and 3 should be fixable, but I apologize I didn't do right now.)

But for most of the cases it works very well for me, so I'd like to share a minimal (not really?!) working example as a starting point for own experiments:

```
PS1="$PS1o"

terminfo_down_sc=$terminfo[cud1]$terminfo[cuu1]$terminfo[sc]$terminfo[cud1]

function zle-statusline() {
  PS1="%{${terminfo_down_sc}$1$terminfo[rc]%}$PS1o"
  zle reset-prompt
}
# taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622943/zsh-vi-mode-status-line
zle -N zle-statusline

function magic-dot() {
if [[ $LBUFFER = *. && $LBUFFER != *{*. && ${${${(z)${:-DUMMY $LBUFFER}}[-1]}[1]} != '/' ]]; then
  LBUFFER+=./
  zle-statusline "[ $(print "$(builtin pwd -P)"/${${(z)${:-DUMMY $LBUFFER}}[-1]} \
                           | perl -pe 's/\n//; $i=0; while($_=~/\.\./ && !($_=~/^\/\./)) { $i++; if($i>100) {print "INFTY!"; exit;} s/\/[^\/]+\/\.\.// }') ]"
elif [[ $LBUFFER = *../ && ${${${(z)${:-DUMMY $LBUFFER}}[-1]}[1]} != '/' ]]; then
  LBUFFER+=../
  zle-statusline "[ $(print "$(builtin pwd -P)"/${${(z)${:-DUMMY $LBUFFER}}[-1]} \
                           | perl -pe 's/\n//; $i=0; while($_=~/\.\./ && !($_=~/^\/\./)) { $i++; if($i>100) {print "INFTY!"; exit;} s/\/[^\/]+\/\.\.// }') ]"
else
  zle self-insert
fi
}
zle -N magic-dot
bindkey "." magic-dot

precmd () { PS1="$PS1o" }
```

Comment: Yep, that works :) Thanks for sharing. I also discovered a "better" cding tool you might be interested in: https://github.com/clvv/fasd

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do `ls ../../..` and then `cd ../../..; ls`. It's possible to do this but I don't really know of what other techniques they have in the documentation for zsh.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing pretty much - it's just too slow though :) I don't want to have to keep track of where exactly my parent is that I want to go to (e.g. 3 levels up), or ls the directory every time.