How do I make zsh auto-complete ".." into "../"
For example, cd ..<tab> doesn't autocomplete into cd ../
I on macOS, and I have tried running with a completely empty .zshrc.
I have also tried adding a specific compdef for .., but that didn't work either.
There's probably already an answer for this question somewhere, but it is hard to search for.

Stumbled across this possible answer by including zstyle in the search.

That didnt work for me...

Make sure you're running the "new" completion system: autoload -Uz compinit; compinit; zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true.

That worked brilliantly! If you add it as an answer, I will accept it!

You might also be interested in that possibility: https://superuser.com/a/912474/195224

From a closed question on StackOverflow:
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true

compinit starts the "new" zsh completion system. "New" is often placed in quotation marks (even in the official docs) because it's almost a couple of decades old.
zstyle is used configure behaviors in zsh.
special-dirs will add . and .. to the list of directories included in completions. It can also be set to include only ...
